# How to add email configuration settings in web.config and retrieve the same from it?

Tags: c#

I want to add the following smtp client configuration in web.config and use it in a c# code behind.

```
    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
        Port = 587,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential("feedback.****", "*****"),
    };
```

How to do it?

Comment: I think you should add `asp.net` tag.

Comment: please elaborate, I am a newbie

Comment: You could just insert the needed values in AppSettings or create your own custom configurationsection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options...

1- If using the .NET Framework `SmtpClient` class you can set up this information in the web.config file to use it as default settings so you don't have to specify them in code...

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="network" from="ben@mailserver.com">
        <network
          host="localhost"
          port="25"
          defaultCredentials="true"
        />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

more info in the [MSDN Smpt documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240(v=vs.110).aspx)...

2- Or, you can set the settings as in the `appSettings` element and then retrieve the settings whenever you need to...

#### web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="EmailHost" value="mail.domain.com"/>
    <add key="EmailPort" value="25"/>
  </appSettings>
```

#### Code

```
var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailHost"],
        Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPort"])
    };
```

Comment: For this kind of hierarchical settings, wouldn't it be better to use key values like `smtp.host`, `smpt.port`, etc...?

Comment: @Krumia I don't see any benefits on using an arbitrary naming convention without a context. The point is that the appSettings keys could be any string you like and it is up to the developer (or team) to follow a specific naming convention...which is perhaps an answer to different question